# How to check if URL parameter exists as a JSON Key and then show its value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a file called data.js with JSON data of a bunch of items. Currently, my code is static and is not using this data.

How can I make the divs dynamically generate so that when I have a lot of different items in the JSON data file this will still work? This way if I go to the URL and type a bunch of parameters from the product codes of the items, they will all show. Example: `?qs=ABC+HJK`

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>

  <style type="text/css">
    .dynamic-content {
      display:none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Default Dynamic Section -->
  <div id="default-content" class="dynamic-content">
    Default content
  </div>
  <!-- Dynamic Section 1 -->
  <div id="apples" class="dynamic-content">
    Apples
  </div>
  <!-- Dynamic Section 2 -->
  <div id="oranges" class="dynamic-content">
    Oranges
  </div>
  <!-- Dynamic Section 3 -->
  <div id="bananas" class="dynamic-content">
    Bananas
  </div>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {

  // Parse the URL parameter
  function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    return url ?? location.href.split(`?${name}=`)[1];
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    const keys = getParameterByName('qs')?.split('+');
    let dynamicContent;

    // For each entry, check whether it correspondents to a div
    if (keys)
      keys.forEach(key => {
        if (key == 'apples')
          dynamicContent = $('#apples');
        else if (key == 'oranges')
          dynamicContent = $('#oranges');
        else if (key == 'bananas')
          dynamicContent = $('#bananas');
        if (dynamicContent)
          dynamicContent.show();
      });

    // If no element is found, show the default one
    if (!dynamicContent)
      $('#default-content').show();
  })
})(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this with vanilla js

example js file

```
objects.js

data = [
    {
        "productNumber":"123",
        "name":"Ex Item 1"
    },
    {
        "productNumber":"142",
        "name":"Ex Item 2"
    },
    {
        "productNumber":"153",
        "name":"Ex Item 3"
    },
    {
        "productNumber":"249",
        "name":"Ex Item 4"
    }
]

function makeDiv(prodNum, prodName){
    exampleDiv = `
            <div>
                <h3>${prodNum}</h3>
                <p>${prodName}</p>
            </div>
    `   
    return exampleDiv
}

const mainDiv = document.querySelector('#mainDiv')

data.forEach(element => {
    productDiv = document.createElement('div');
    productDiv.innerHTML = makeDiv(element.productNumber, element.name)
    mainDiv.appendChild(productDiv)
});
```

html file

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainDiv"></div>

    <script src="objects.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

then you can give classes and ids to the generated elements and you can put an if  to check if the data is empty and one div on the html with the default content or set the default in the js file

Comment: Hey, thanks but what happens to the URL functionality I currently have? How can I make it so that when I type the parameters at the end of the URL as I did before, this time with the productCode, it will list those products only?

Comment: From the query string check the paramenters you have passed and generate the json from whatever source you have, then you just have the list that you want to show.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm still confused on how to check if the parameters exist in the objects.js file